# notifyDataSetChanged not work with FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using `FragmentPageAdapter` for my `ViewPager` with `Fragments`. Each `Fragment` contains adapter with small gallery.

On some fragments ex. `n` position, I have button which change gallery. When I update dataset for this inner adapter, I'm trying to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my `FragmentPageAdapter`, but it doesn't refresh my view.

But if I switch to `n+2` fragment, and then back to `n` fragment, gallery is updated like it should. Looks like it stores it in memory...

So the problem is:
How to force `FragmentPageAdapter` to recreate view on **current** position (current visible) fragment only?

Comment: Posting some code around the problem will be useful.

Comment: I believe the solution is to override `getItemPosition(Object)` and return `POSITION_NONE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to override `getItemPosition(Object)` and return `POSITION_NONE`.

This forces the `PagerAdapter` to recreate the fragments that you've loaded, by checking if their position in the adapter has changed. Since it has, and you are replacing an "old" fragment with a "newer" one, you tell the adapter that the current fragment has no position and you need it to reload what should be at that spot.

Comment: OK, I checked it. It doesn't work on first fragment (I mean, if I don't change fragment, it will still be the same). If I go to `n+2` and then go back, when I change gallery it works like it should. Any suggestion?

Comment: OK, nvm. I was using wrong position to update data, problem solved with overriding that method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Viewpager.setOffScreenPageLimit method to determine the amount of pages the view pager loads on advance based on your current page. Yes,  the behavior you described is perfectly fine - I think that the default amount is 1 ahead. I don't know how many pages you have but try setting it to 2-3 and see how it works for you.

Cheers!

Comment: I know about `setOffScreenPageLimit` - this is the reason why it is in memory and I need to keep it.